# C#: Config file error

Tags: c#, config

I created a `.config` file in which I had not given any `<configuration>` tag. It works fine in my project. But now when I created the unit test case for the project, it is giving an exception that `project.dll` doesn't have `<configuration>` tag. If I include the tag in the `.config` file the project is giving an error. I am using vs-2008. I created the `.config` file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <appSettings>
....
.....
</appSettings>
```

If I use `<configuration>` tag in `.config` file the error comes in the project and testcase works fine. the error comes as:

> The root element must match the name of the section referencing the
>   file, 'appSettings'

As I remove the `<configuration>` tag, the error comes in unit testcase as:

```
unit test runner failed to  load test assembly.
jetbrains.resharper.taskrunnerframework.taskexception.configuration system fail to initialize.
jetbrains.resharper.taskrunnerframework.taskexception.configuration file project.dll doesnot have <configuration> tag.
```

Comment: Please post the exact errors you are getting in both cases.

Comment: `.config` file without `<configuration>` is not configuration file, it's just another meaningless XML file..

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap the `<appSettings>` in a `<configuration>` section. e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    ...
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: if i wrap the <appsetting> in <configuration> the production code is throwing an error

Comment: What is the exception? note that the XML is case sensitive, it has to be <appSettings>, not <appsetting>